# javascript build filter function at runtime

Tags: javascript, function

While I go into my use-case in (hopefully not too much) detail below, keep in mind that the fundamental question is "How do I create a customized function at runtime in javascript?"

I have (potentially large) arrays of objects, and the user can build custom searches on those objects. The search function is passed an array of filters of the form

```
[{field:'name', predicate:'contains', modifier:'Joe'}, 
 {field:'type', predicate:'is', modifier:'Boss'}]
```

which in this example would return all bosses named Joe.

Toward that end, I created a filtering function that applies the filters to the master list, which looks something like:

```
var matches = everythingOfThatType;
whereClause.forEach(function(filter) {
switch(filter.predicate) {
    case '=':
    case 'is':
        matches = matches.filter(function(record) { return record[filter.field] == filter.modifier; });
        console.log(filter, matches);
        break;
    case '!=':
    case 'is not':
        matches = matches.filter(function(record) { return record[filter.field] != filter.modifier; });
        console.log(filter, matches);
        break;
    ...
```

and so on.

It's working all right, but now I'm getting some gnarly complexity (special rules for filter combinations, recursive filtering on array properties, etc.), and for performance it would be better to only iterate through the list of all candidates once anyway.

my ideal solution would look something like

```
var filterFunc = magicallyCreateFilterFunc(filters);
var matches = everythingOfThatType.filter(filterFunc);
```

where `magicallyCreateFilterFunc()` would have something like the original switch statement, but instead of applying the filter, would add a line to the function that would eventually be applied to all the objects. Then I can add all the other complexity and recursion and whatnot in a tight, efficient manner.

It seems to me that JavaScript is well-suited for this sort of task (as an aside, the deeper I get into JavaScript the more I appreciate its depth), but I'm a little stuck on step 1: dynamically define a function based on data at run-time. I would really appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: If you don't have to re-invent the wheel due to client restrictions, you could use [lazy.js](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/) or one of its competitors.

Comment: Lazy.js looks interesting. I'll definitely study it to see if I can make it work for me. However I'd still like to be able to roll my own, even if I choose not to :) .

Comment: Looking at how the template libraries like Underscore work, they use `new Function()` to create a function from a text string. This could potentially do the job; I'm still poking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a simple, clean way to do this. What I didn't know when I asked this question oh, so long ago is that closures and filters are best pals.

Rather than apply the filters in the switch statement, I can add the filter functions to an array, then use a closure to execute all the functions on each member of the array.

So my switch statement above looks more like

```
var buildFilterList = function(whereClause) {
    var filterFunctions = [];
    whereClause.forEach(function(filter) {
        switch(filter.predicate) {
            case '=':
            case 'is':
                filterFunctions.push((function(field) { return function(record) { return record[filter.field] == filter.modifier; })})(field));
                break;
...
```

Which gives me a list of functions to apply to each element, *each in a closure that contains the field it should be applied to*. More complex filter functions could have more parameters. Now, how to efficiently take that list of filters and apply them? Closures again.

```
var filterApplicator = function(filters) {
    return function(item) {
        var passed = true, i = 0, filterCount = filters.length;
        for (i = 0; passed && i < filterCount; i++) {
            passed = filters[i](item);
        }
        return passed;
    }
}

var filterFunctions = buildFilterList(whereClause);
matches = everythingOfThatType.filter(filterApplicator(filterFunctions));
```

`filterApplicator()` returns a function that will be applied to each element in the original array. That function is in a closure that includes the array of filter functions, so all it has to do is loop through those functions and apply them on the element until one fails.

(It should be noted that I have not tested this exact syntax, but the basic concept is what I wanted to pass on here.)